# Evaluation of SQL Query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I currently have two versions of SQL query and I am trying to understand which could be better in terms of performance, cost etc.

This is wrt this question : [Average Salary: Departments VS Company](https://leetcode.com/articles/average-salary-departments-vs-company/)

```
select department_salary.pay_month, department_id,
case
  when department_avg>company_avg then 'higher'
  when department_avg<company_avg then 'lower'
  else 'same'
end as comparison
from
(
  select department_id,
         avg(amount) as department_avg,
         date_format(pay_date, '%Y-%m') as pay_month
      from salary
      join employee on salary.employee_id = employee.employee_id
      group by department_id, pay_month
) as department_salary
join
(
  select avg(amount) as company_avg,
         date_format(pay_date, '%Y-%m') as pay_month
      from salary
      group by date_format(pay_date, '%Y-%m')
) as company_salary
on department_salary.pay_month = company_salary.pay_month
;
```

My question is instead of joining, they could have instead used the second table in the case statement itself.

```
select a.pay_month,
       a.department_id,
       (case when avg(a.salary) > (
             select avg(e.salary)
                 from employee e
                 where e.pay_month = a.pay_month)
        then 'higher'
        else 'lower' end) as comparison
from employee a
group by a.pay_month,a.department_id;
```

Which is better? Is join really necessary?

Comment: If you don't know how to read an execution plan for MySQL, read up on them. That'll help you better compare the two queries.

Comment: Personally I always avoid nested correlated queries in the select list as I think its ugly and difficult to read. I would always use the join method, or the same with a CTE if you are hip. As @Shawn says check the execution plan. I wouldn't be surprised to see them being exactly the same in which case readability is the key.

Comment: Please qualify each column in a JOIN with the table it lives in.

Comment: What version are you running?  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` in each case.

Answer (score 1):

To determine which is "better", you should test the performance.  Sometimes, performance using correlated subqueries is much better than the explicit `join` alternative.

When you ask:  "Is join really necessary?"  I think you mean "Is `join` really necessary".  Obviously, you can sometimes express a query without an explicit `join`.  Under the hood, though, the database is implementing a join-algorithm (probably either nested loop or index-lookup) to do the work.

That pretty much answers the question.  SQL often provides multiple ways to accomplish the same goal.  So, you can often express logic with a `join` or without a `join`.  Just one caveat:  the correlated subquery is really equivalent to a `left join` and not an `inner join`.